# RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded While setting min-max date

Tags: reactjs, datepicker, flatpickr

I am facing Maximum call stack size exceeded issue while setting min-max date for date picker.
I am having two date picker (stare date, end date). When I am selecting start date I am setting min date for end date picker and when I am selecting end date I am setting max date for start date picker.

Providing the sand box for the same.

[Code Sandbox Example](https://codesandbox.io/s/lrnmx4qppl)

Below I am providing the code for the same:

**Flatpickr Component**

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import Flatpickr from 'react-flatpickr';
import 'flatpickr/dist/flatpickr.min.css';
import 'flatpickr/dist/themes/light.css';

export default class DatePicker extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.setDate = this.setDate.bind(this);
    this.setDatePickerProps = this.setDatePickerProps.bind(this);

    this.state = {
      selectValue: props.selectValue ? props.selectValue : "",
      options: props.options ? props.options : {},
      placeholder: props.placeholder ? props.placeholder : {}
    };
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps(newProps){
    this.setState({
      selectValue: newProps.selectValue ? newProps.selectValue : "",
      options: newProps.options ? newProps.options : {},
      placeholder: newProps.placeholder ? newProps.placeholder : {}
        });
  }

  setDatePickerProps(propKey, propValue){
    this.refs.refDatePicker.flatpickr.set(propKey, propValue);
  }

  clearDate(){
    this.refs.refDatePicker.flatpickr.clear();
  }

  setDate(newValue){
    this.setState({
             selectValue: newValue ? newValue : ""
        });
    if(this.props.onChange){
      this.props.onChange(newValue);
    }
  }

  render(){
    return (
      <Flatpickr className="form-control clickable" ref="refDatePicker" placeholder={this.state.placeholder} options={this.state.options} value={this.state.selectValue} onValueUpdate={this.setDate} />
    );
  }
}
```

Below is the code for setting min and max date on parent component.

```
onFilterDateChange(str, date){
    if(str === "start"){
      this.refEndDatePicker.setDatePickerProps("minDate", date[0] ? date[0] : "");
      this.setState({
        objSearch: Object.assign({},this.state.objSearch,{ startDate: date[0] ? date[0] : ""})
      });
    }
    else if(str === "end"){
      this.refStartDatePicker.setDatePickerProps("maxDate", date[0] ? date[0] : "");
      this.setState({
        objSearch: Object.assign({},this.state.objSearch,{ endDate: date[0] ? date[0] : ""})
      });
    }
  }
```

When I select start date everything works fine but as soon as I select end date after that it shows this error **"RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded"**.

**Environment Information**

flatpickr version used: 3.6.4

Browser name and version: Chrome, Version 70.0.3538.110 (Official Build) (64-bit)

OS and version: Windows 10 Pro

Comment: you should never(!) call setState in componentWillReceiveProps. 
( you probably dont need componentWillReceiveProps at all ;) )

this function gets called whenever the props or the state is changed and you will then change the state so the function gets called again and again and again ... until there is an infinite loop.

After React 16.6 they recommend to use getDerivedStateFromProps instead, if needed.

https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html

Comment: @LorenzWeiß I tried removing componentWillReceiveProps but still I am facing the same.